# Bundle.main.url is unable to locate plist saved with PropertyListSerialization

Tags: ios, swift, plist, nsfilemanager

I'm reading from and writing to `plist`, but one of the two processes is not working.

**Reading**

```swift
var data: [String: Int] = [:]
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Calendar", withExtension: "plist") {
    do {
        print("url: \(url)")
        let dataContent = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: dataContent, format: nil) as? [String: Int] {
            data = dict
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

`url` here is not being printed which means `Bundle.main.url` is either unable to locate `Calendar.plist` or it's not being saved properly.

**Writing**

```swift
do {
    let path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("Calendar.plist")
    let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: data, format: .xml, options: 0)
    try plistData.write(to: path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`data` is `["test": 1]` tentatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are doing:

- when reading, you read your `Calendar.plist` from the app's bundle root folder.
- when writing, you write your `Calendar.plist` into the app's bundle `Documents` folder.

Since the app's bundle root folder (from where you're reading) is not writable for you, the proper location for your `Calendar.plist` is `Documents` folder, and you should create the URL or path for it in the same way as you do it when writing, better in a dedicated getter that you call from both reading and writing routines.

```
func calendarURL() -> URL? {
    guard let result = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("Calendar.plist") else { return nil }
    return result
}
```

**Reading**

```
var data: [String: Int] = [:]
if let url = calendarURL() {
    ...
```

**Writing**

```
if let path = calendarURL() {
    do {
        let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: data, format: .xml, options: 0)
        ...
```